# How to return an error if you have an empty DynamoDB response?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I want to make it so that if there is nothing in the response from DynamoDB, it returns an error (not sure on 204 or 404). I did try adding an if statement into the try which checked if the number of items was equal to 0 then it would manually set the response code (this worked) however I was wondering if there was a better way of doing it. Another post I found identified that it's intended behaviour for it to not throw an error but i Want it to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64939364/9478747

```
const length = Object.keys(body).length;
if (length == 0) {
    statusCode = 404;
}
```

```
export const handler: Handler = async (event, context) => {
  let body;
  let statusCode = 200;
  const headers = {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers":
      "Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  };

  try {
    body = await dynamo
      .get({
        TableName: "Table",
        Key: {
          id: event.pathParameters.id,
        },
      })
      .promise();
  } catch (err: any) {
    statusCode = 400;
    body = err.message;
  } finally {
    body = JSON.stringify(body);
  }

  return {
    statusCode,
    body,
    headers,
  };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

DynamoDB returns an empty object if the item does not exist, this results in a 200 statusCode as the request was successful.

Your check is doing the right thing, I would continue with that approach. You can determine which statsCode you like to send depending on how you want to handle that event downstream.

```
export const handler: Handler = async (event, context) => {
  let body;
  let statusCode = 200;
  const headers = {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers":
      "Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  };

  try {
    body = await dynamo
      .get({
        TableName: "Table",
        Key: {
          id: event.pathParameters.id,
        },
      })
      .promise();

    statusCode = Object.keys(body).length > 0? 200: 404;

  } catch (err: any) {
    statusCode = 400;
    body = err.message;
  } finally {
    body = JSON.stringify(body);
  }

  return {
    statusCode,
    body,
    headers,
  };
};
```

Comment: What error would you say is more suitable for an emtpy DynamoDB response a 204 or 404 response?

Comment: It's totally dependent on how your application will handle the errors. Do you want to retry etc... There's no right or wrong way, just as long as you know how to handle it properly downstream. Error codes are created to define what you do with it when you receive it.